# How to cache stuff only once in a timespan from a device in .NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, memorycache

I am trying to implement a simple caching in my backend (.NET core) of website. What I want to do is cache the number of times a GET request is called, but I want to do it only once for a device in some timespan.

What I mean is if some (user)device sends a GET request to view data `A`, then I want to count it as `A` requested once, but if the same person reload the page in (for example) 2 minutes again then I don't want to count it as a new request. But, after 2 minutes if the same device requests the data `A` again then I want to count it.

What I am currently using is simple `MemoryCache`. I have unique keys for each data, and I count the number of times the data is requested like follows:

```
if (_cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out numberOfTimes))
{
    _cache.Set(cacheKey, numberOfTimes + 1, cacheOptions);
}
else 
{
    _cache.Set(cacheKey, numberOfTimes, cacheOptions);
}
```

But, I am not able to understand how can I mark the request from the same (user)device under a certain timespan as to not be counted. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What about [response caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: what sort of mechanism do you use to distinguish between devices? (.net sessions? pre-generated device IDs in custom headers? something else?)

Comment: If you want to count only once in a given time span, you need to store when the user did the request (if lastCountedRequestDateTime < now - myTimespan then count it). To identify users (browsers) you can use cookies if you have no authentication.